# On Zero-Free Regions for $\zeta(s)$ and $L(s,\chi)$ with $|t| \le 2$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I'm reading the proof from [Hildebrand](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/) that for some $c_1 > 0$, the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ has no zero in the region $\sigma > 1-c_1$, $|t| \le 2$. (Here $s = \sigma + it$ per tradition).

After showing that $\zeta$ is zero-free for $\sigma \ge 1$, the author writes:

> . . . since $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros in the closed half-plane $\sigma \ge 1$, so $1 / \zeta(s)$ is analytic in this half-plane and therefore bonuded in any compact region contained in this half-plane. In particular, $1/\zeta(s)$ is bounded in the rectangle $1 \le \sigma \le 2$, $|t| \le 2$. **By compactness, it follows that $1/\zeta(s)$ remains bounded in any sufficiently small neighborhoood of this rctangle**, and, in particular, in a rectangle of the [desired form].

I have two questions about this:

(i) Why is the bolded statement true?

(ii) Where does this argument break down if we replace $\zeta(s)$ by $L(s, \chi)$? After all, $L(s, \chi)$ also has the property of being zero-free in the region $\sigma \ge 1$, but [we don't have a similar conclusion for $L(s, \chi)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero).

Comment: We do have a similar conclusion for $L(s,\chi)$.  The problem is that $c_1$ depends on $\chi$, and might be extremely small as a function of the conductor.